# webapp does not appear on firebase dashboard alongside android app

Tags: android, firebase, web-applications

I'm working on an android app and using Firebase. I'd like to have a webapp alongside this android app in the same project. When I click on the option to add a webapp I just get the script-tag for the HTML page. Serving the page locally works but nothing appears on the console indicating that there is also a webapp in this project. Is this normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed the expected behavior. Web apps are managed differently than Android and iOS apps and never show in your list of apps.

Comment: Thank you! I thought I was going crazy.